# Spring prefix using @ConfigurationProperties with @Value in the constructor

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I am running my application with Spring Boot (1.2.0.RELEASE) using the @SpringBootApplication annotation.

What I try to achieve is to have the following without using long prefixes in each @Value annotation:

application.properties

```
prefix.key1=value1
prefix.key2=value2
```

DefaultService.java

```
@Service
@ConfigurationProperties("prefix")
public class DefaultService implements Service {
    private final String key1;
    private final String key2;

    @Autowired
    public DefaultService(@Value("${key1}") final String key1, @Value("${key2}") final String key2) {
        this.key1 = key1;
        this.key2 = key2;
    }
}
```

I know that this can be done without using @Value and in need of setters ([@ConfigurationProperties prefix not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27416327/configurationproperties-prefix-not-working)) or with http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.2.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-external-config-typesafe-configuration-properties but I try to achieve it in the constructor.

Comment: I guess long prefixes are the only option in your scenario.

Comment: This would be a nice Spring feature request.

Answer (score 5):

I am not sure about the usage of @value, but the following works for me

```
@Service
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="prefix")
public class DefaultService {
    private String key1;
    private String key2;


    @PostConstruct
    public void report(){
        System.out.println(String.format("key1=%s,key2=%s", key1,key2));
    }
    public void setKey1(String key1) {
        this.key1 = key1;
    }

    public void setKey2(String key2) {
        this.key2 = key2;
    }
```

application.properties

```
prefix.key1=value1
prefix.key2=value2
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```java
@Service
public class DefaultService {

    private final String key1;
    private final String key2;

    @Autowired
    public DefaultService(ConfigSettings config) {
        this.key1 = config.getKey1();
        this.key2 = config.getKey2();
    }

    @Component
    @ConfigurationProperties("prefix")
    static class ConfigSettings {
        private String key1;
        private String key2;

        public String getKey1() {
            return key1;
        }
        public String getKey2() {
            return key2;
        }
        public void setKey1(String key1) {
            this.key1 = key1;
        }
        public void setKey2(String key2) {
            this.key2 = key2;
        }
    }

}
```