# Spring Boot Configuration Properties to inject map not working

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have been trying to inject map from custom configuration file. However somehow it didn't worked. Below if the bean of configuration.

```
@Component
@EnableConfigurationProperties
@ConfigurationProperties
@PropertySource("classpath:pro-idp-properties.properties")
public class IDPConfig {
    private  final Map<String, String> configMap = new HashMap<>();

    public Map<String, String> getConfigMap() {
        return configMap;
    }
}
```

Can anybody tell me what am I doing wrong ? I followed this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27749036/2887739) to retry but I think I have bad day today :(

Answer (score 1):

Finally found the solution. What I was doing wrong is I had used/configured wrong configuration file. Corrected it and it is working fine. Below is the minimal annotations that anyone should use to inject map in the code.

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:/pro-idp-properties.properties")
@ConfigurationProperties
public class IDPConfig {
   private  final Map<String, String> events = new HashMap<>();

   public Map<String, String> getEvents() {
    return events;
   }
}
```

**Configuration file **

```
events.name1=value1
events.name2=value2
events.name12=value1
events.name22=value2
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a setter for the map field.

Comment: No need to use setter if we are using collection and it is initialized. I have tried it and it is working. Thanks for your suggestion.