# Spring Boot loading a list from a config file returns empty list

Tags: java, spring-boot, configuration, yaml

I just created a really basic spring boot application using spring initializer and am trying things out. I want to load a list from a yaml configuration file, but it always returns empty.

I have a custom configuration class

```
@ConfigurationProperties("example-unit")
@EnableConfigurationProperties
public class ConfigurationUnit {

    public List<String> confiList = new ArrayList<>();

    public List<String> getConfiList() {
        return this.confiList;
    }

}
```

And my main class looks like this

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

    static ConfigurationUnit configurationUnit = new ConfigurationUnit();


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);

        List<String> hello = configurationUnit.getConfiList();

        System.out.print("");
    }

}
```

I have put the application.yaml into resources folder.

```
example-unit:
  - string1
  - string2
  - hello22
```

I searched here and online, but can't figure out what's the issue and nothing I changed helped. I know I must be doing something wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This statement is wrong `static ConfigurationUnit configurationUnit = new ConfigurationUnit();`
 you should not create the object

Spring only injects the properties into the beans that are handled by application context, and spring creates beans of classes that are annotated with `@ Configuration`

**ConfigurationUnit**

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties("example-unit")
public class ConfigurationUnit {

public List<String> confiList;

public List<String> getConfiList() {
    return this.confiList;
    }

 }
```

**DemoApplication** In the spring boot main get the bean from applicationcontext and from it get the list object

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    ApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
     ConfigurationUnit unit = context.getBean("configurationUnit"):

    System.out.print(unit. getConfiList());
   }

}
```

Comment: good point. I oversaw the `static ConfigurationUnit` declaration in Application class. That of course disturbs the whole bean-injection magic Spring is known for.

Comment: Thanks, yeah that is the main mistake I made. Not using the bean spring boot creates with @Configuration. And also it seems to be sensitive to naming so I had to add example-unit.confi-list: to the header of yaml file so that it recognizes the list by its name, so it can instantiate it with values from the config.

Answer (score 1):

Put your list under *prefix.property*. In your case `example-unit.confi-list:`. Usually provide a setter for your property: `setConfiList(List<String> strings)`. But since you already initialized it as empty Array list this setter is obsolete says [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27416327/configurationproperties-prefix-not-working). There is also advice to add Enable-annotation to Application class:

> Application class should have @EnableConfigurationProperties annotation

Comment: Tried this and it still returns an empty list, but thanks for answering.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the reference on how [Spring Bboot Configurtion Binding](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-Configuration-Binding) works.

Specifically for your question, this is an example of app that achives your goal:

- application.yml

```
example-unit:
  confiList:
    - string1
    - string2
    - hello22
```

- sources

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableConfigurationProperties(ConfigurationUnit.class)
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ConfigurableApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
        ConfigurationUnit configurationUnit = context.getBean(ConfigurationUnit.class);
        System.out.println(configurationUnit.getConfiList());
    }

}

@ConfigurationProperties("example-unit")
public class ConfigurationUnit {

    public List<String> confiList = new ArrayList<>();

    public List<String> getConfiList() {
        return this.confiList;
    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is an example :

***Application.yml:***

```
example-unit: string1,string2,hello22
```

**ConfigurationUnit.class:**

```
@Component
@PropertySource(value="classpath:application.yml")
public class ConfigurationUnit {

    @Value("#{'${example-unit}'.split(',')}")
    private List<String> confiList;

    public List<String> getConfiList() {
        return confiList;
    }
}
```

**DemoFileLoadApplication.class:**

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoFileLoadApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ConfigurableApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(DemoFileLoadApplication.class, args);
        ConfigurationUnit configurationUnit = context.getBean(ConfigurationUnit.class);
        System.out.println(configurationUnit.getConfiList());
    }
}
```

**Output:**

> [string1, string2, hello22]