# @ConfigurationProperties(prefix="app-props") is not working in spring-boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, configurationproperties

application.yaml

```
app-props:
  uuidMap:
    customerId: "af241470-7a1a-41b9-8861-33c37069b8f2"
    resourceId: "213e8652-bb34-4709-bc4b-a3ad1587f619"
```

AppProps class:

```
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="app-props")
public class AppProps
{
  private Map<String, String> uuidMap;

  public Map<String, String> getUuidMap() {
    return uuidMap;
  }

  public void setUuidMap(Map<String, String> uuidMap) {
    this.uuidMap = uuidMap;
  }
}
```

MyClass:

```
@Component
public class MyClass
{
  @Autowired
  private AppProps appProps;

  public void printInfo()
  {
    Map<String, String> uuidMap = appProps.getUuidMap();
    String customerId = uuidMap.get("customerId");
    System.out.println(customerId);
  }
}
```

Main class

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableConfigurationProperties
public class MainEntry  {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
      AnnotationConfigApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(MainEntry.class);

      MyClass myClass = context.getBean(MyClass.class);
      myClass.printInfo();
      context.close();
    }
}
```

When running the main class, the myClass.uuidMap is null and I got:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot
> invoke "java.util.Map.get(Object)" because "uuidMap" is null  at
> project1.MyClass.printInfo(MyClass.java:18)   at
> project1.MainEntry.main(MainEntry.java:27)

How to fix this and get the member variable `uuidMap` populated with the data in `application.yaml`?

I noticed that there is a similar question [@ConfigurationProperties prefix not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27416327/configurationproperties-prefix-not-working). But the difference is that I have the setter in `AppProps`, and The uuidMap is a map not just a String. Also, I got a warning `Spring Boot Configuration Annotation Processor not configured` in a red bar on my IntelliJ and I am not sure if that is related.

Comment: Youa ren't using spring boot to launch the application. You need to use `SpringApplication.run(MainEntry.class, args);` to start the application. The configuration binding is a Spring Boot feature, without using the proper mechanisms this won't work.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @M.Deinum. changing main class as below solved the problem

```
public class MainEntry  {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(MainEntry.class);
      ConfigurableApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(MainEntry.class, args);
      MyClass myClass = context.getBean(MyClass.class);
      myClass.printInfo();
      context.close();
    }
```